# gtk library is not correctly searched and linked

Tags: linux, gcc, clang, gtk

I am on ubuntu22.04 and i built a local gtk library that i want to link to. However, my program always finds the system library.

I just discovered that the reason for it is the gtk lib name and the linker argument i am trying to use.

This is the linker command i have

`gcc -o prog prog.o -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN', -Wl,-rpath-link,'$ORIGIN' l -L"someother.sodir" -l"glib..."  "/full/path/to/lib/libgtk-3.so.0" (tried all the 3 different ones below)`

however, gtk build script compiled 3 libraries and their relation are as below:

1. libgtk-3.so.0  -> libgtk-3.so.0.2400.0
2. libgtk-3.so -> libgtk-3.so.0
3. libgtk-3.so.0.2400.0

so apparently the 1 and 2 are both symbolic links to 3. When doing readelf -a on 3, it shows the actual library name is libgtk-3.so.0, so i just renamed libgtk-3.so.0.2400.0 to libgtk-3.so.0 and got rid of the others, and wallah, it worked.

My question here is then, why can't the linker find the library given the actual path? Why the path needs to match the library name?

I am very suspicious about this flag -Wl,-rpath-link with $ORIGIN. I just discovered that before renaming the file, linker actually searches the current dir since the $ORIGIN I passed and since i copied the symbolic link .so into the current dir, it does not find it, and once i removed the symbolic link and put the file directly into the current path, it does found it. But it still does not look into the hardcoded path that i used, which should be the 1st priority to linker?